# Removing extra padding from StaticText/TextFields

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to remove the extra padding in text fields/static text fields?  Here's an example:

EDIT: I don't mean the width of the text field, I'm referring to the height.

[image: Extra padding]

I have the pixel size of the text field set to the lowest possible number without the text disappearing.

The padding on the field is set to 0.

I'm finding that I'm wasting a ton of extra space with this padding. I'm not sure I'm able to fit the required information in a one page report with the font sizes I'm required to use.

Comment: You can reduce height of text field and also font size of text to reduce extra padding.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment.  My problem is I need to use a specific font size for certain elements.  I can't change the font size, and I can't adjust the text field size past a certain point because there's some extra padding.  The solution I came across below does the trick for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to do it, although kind of hacky.

It's the "box" element that's providing the padding (for borders).
In order to remove the padding, set the box padding to -1 like so:

```
<staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="271" width="160" height="15" uuid="325acf4c-c003-4d50-aa1e-a3ae1c8f0dff">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box padding="-1"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Answer (score 2):

minus is also working in padding. Below code did save me. Please note in below code i am using minus thirteen. As you incerese minus number, padding becomes smaller and smaller.

```
<box topPadding="-13" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="-13" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
                </box>
```